# Table content alignment to centre using tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I wish to put the second and third columns in equal length and in center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    %\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Y*{3}{W}@{}}
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Testing Testing Testin}} \\
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Making into Secondline (\%)}} \\
     \cmidrule{2-3}
    & \small {\textbf{AA}}
     & \small {\textbf{BB}} \\
     \midrule
    Test 1 & 33 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Outcome:

[image]

I wish to put the second and third columns in equal length and in center.

I had tried :

```
 \begin{tabular}{ccc}
```

Comment: I suppose you means second and third *columns*? What width?

Comment: @Bernard, yes, columns. I will edit my questions again.

The width should be same for both second and third columns.

Comment: What will be the real content of these columns?

Comment: @Bernard, it is just percentages of number (for example: 50%, 100%, 40%)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way with the help of `parbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    %\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Y*{3}{W}@{}}
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Testing Testing Testin}} \\
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Making into Secondline (\%)}} \\
     \cmidrule{2-3}
    &  {\parbox{3cm}{\small\hfil\textbf{AA}\hfill}}
     & {\parbox{3cm}{\small\hfil\textbf{BB}\hfill}} \\
     \midrule
    Test 1 & 33 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution, based on `siunitx` to have a nice alignment of numbers (centred right-aligned). Non-numbers in `S` columns have to be surrounded by a pair of braces and are automatically centred. Furthermore, the width of S columns can be chosen. This solution also relies on `makecell`, which allows for line breaks in standard cells, and a common  formatting of the arguments of the `\makecell` and `\thead` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=3.0, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.5cm}
 \begin{tabular}{cSS}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\small\bfseries Testing Testing Testin} \\
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{Making into Secondline}\\ (\%)}} \\
     \cmidrule{2-3}
    &{\small \textbf{AA}}
     & {\small\textbf{BB}} \\
     \midrule
    Test 1 & 33 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
    Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My clipboard manager struck again! Thank you for pointing it! I'll fix that within seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This make columns "Z", centered with exactly the half width of the longest header line. You have only to say to LateX what is the width of that header line, before of each tabular, width `\settowidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\newlength{\xxx} % suggestion:  change "xxx" for something meaningful 
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\hfil}p{.5\xxx}}
\begin{document}

\settowidth{\xxx}{\textbf{Making into Secondline (\%)}}

\begin{tabular}{cZZ} \toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Testing Testing Testin}} \\
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Making into Secondline (\%)}} \\\cmidrule{2-3}
& \small {\textbf{AA}}  & \small {\textbf{BB}} \\\midrule
Test 1 & 33 & 73 \\
Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\
Test 2 & 57 & 73 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]